# How to merge two input fields using attribute mutator?

Tags: php, laravel

It's clear how to set and get attributes when it's about one field. But how can I merge two input fields using attribute mutator?

For example I have `publish_date` and `publish_time`, which I insert in the DB together and want to set attribute `publish_date` to become `publish_date` + `publish_time`.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab other attributes from the attributes array on the model.

```
public function setPublishDateAttribute($value) 
{
    $this->attributes['publish_date'] = $value + $this->attributes['publish_time'];
}
```

Comment: It throws exception " undefined index publish_date"